# Orbit space of $S^5$ under certain action

Tags: group-actions, cw-complexes

Let $Z/6 = <w| w^6 = 1>$.Consider a $Z/6$-action on $S^5$ as generated by the relation $w.(z_1 , z_2 , z_3 ) = (wz_1 , w^2z_2 , w^3z_3)$ ,where $(z_1,z_2,z_3)$ belongs to $S^5$.

Question 1: What is the orbit space of $S^5$ under this action? i.e. What is $S^5/(Z/6)$ ?

Question 2:What is $Z/6$-CW complex structure of $S^5$ with the above action ?

Need help for solve these questions.